# Android Using AlertDialog Alongside Snackbar

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-snackbar, snackbar

I'm developing an android application that deals with databases and records. The user has an option to delete a record and I'm having trouble deciding how to go about doing this. My options are:

1. Use an `AlertDialog` that pops up before the record is deleted and confirms the user's choice to delete.
2. Use a `Snackbar` that comes up after the user deletes, telling them that the record has been deleted, and giving them the option to UNDO.
3. Use both an `AlertDialog` before deleting (asking for confirmation) and a `Snackbar` after deleting (With an UNDO action).

I actually prefer `Snackbars` over `AlertDialogs` but I don't know if having both together is the best way to go. So I'm confused as to what the correct approach should be. I tried looking for any guidelines or best practices in the developer documentation, but couldn't find any regarding this issue. So what's the best practice in this case?